# error in code jqueryAjax online webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

please tell me whats problem in the code status is 200 ok but unable to recieve record from web service (response) it is showing error null
 Please help me i am try to solving it from 2 days...

```
            var webMethod = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit?callback=?";
             var soap ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <soap:Body>     <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <Celsius>12</Celsius> </CelsiusToFahrenheit>   </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>';
            $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url :webMethod,
                  data: soap,
                   dataType :"xml",
                  contentType:"text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                  cache:false,
                  async: false,
                error:function(resp)
                {
                    alert("Error :"+$j.parseXML(resp));
                },

            }).done(function(response){

                    console.log(response);
                    var xmlData =$j(response).find('FahrenheitToCelsiusResult').text();
                    alert(xmlData);
                }); 

        });
```

Comment: this is result of console
[11:50:33.228] OPTIONS http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 472ms]

Answer (score 0):

in the case that you get a code status 200, it means that the request is send ok and the response is send from server also ok. So, there is no problem in that.

What might be you problem for getting null as a response is

1. What you pass to the server is wrong (and the server cannot do any calculations on your data)
2. The server's web service may not work as intended and gives you that null response

Comment: when i am loading html file it is showing error but in console it is showing [11:50:33.228] OPTIONS http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 472ms]
i need some requested data like pasing record abc and it should retrun list of records